# Logging to file with todays date in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm trying to log into file `root.$date.log` where `date` is day when log was submitted.

Right now I created this appender, but problem that I have is that `timestamp` is only evaluated once (when Tomcat starts)

```
appender("STDOUT", FileAppender) {

    file = "$logDirectory/logs/root.${timestamp("yyyy-MM-dd")}.log"
    append = true
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = loggerPattern
    }
}
```

PS
I'm using Grails 3.0.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a simple `FileAppender`, you should use a `RollingFileAppender` which can create a new log file based on rolling policy.

Using [logback's](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html) rolling file appender.

```
appender("ROLLING", RollingFileAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        Pattern = "%d %level %thread %mdc %logger - %m%n"
    }
    rollingPolicy(TimeBasedRollingPolicy) {
        FileNamePattern = "$logDirectory/logs/root-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.zip"
    }
}
```

If you want to use Log4J, you can use `DailyRollingFileAppender`. But the default implementation has some issues:

> DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization
>   issues and data loss.  The log4j extras companion includes
>   alternatives which should be considered for new deployments and which
>   are discussed in the documentation for
>   org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.

There are some custom implementations available out there with name `CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender` which you can use. This also lets you specify the number of backup files to keep. And also on daily basis it can compress the previous day log file to save you space. I'm not adding any particular link as that might broke in near future. Instead I'm adding the implementation that we have been using in our project from past couple of months without any issues.

```
package org.apache.log4j

import org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent
import org.apache.tools.zip.ZipEntry
import org.apache.tools.zip.ZipOutputStream

import java.lang.reflect.Field
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

class CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender extends DailyRollingFileAppender {
    String datePattern = "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    boolean compress
    Integer maxNumberOfDays = 7

    /**
     * The next time we estimate a rollover should occur.
     */
    private long nextCheck = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1

    /*
    * This method checks to see if we're exceeding the number of log backups
    * that we are supposed to keep, and if so, deletes the offending files.
    * It then delegates to the rollover method to rollover to a new file if
    * required.
    */

    protected void cleanupAndRollOver() throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fileName)
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -maxNumberOfDays)

        Field field_sdf = DailyRollingFileAppender.getDeclaredField("sdf")
        field_sdf.setAccessible(true)
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = field_sdf.get(this) as SimpleDateFormat

        Date cutoffDate = cal.getTime()
        if (file.getParentFile().exists()) {
            File[] files = file.getParentFile().listFiles(new StartsWithFileFilter(file.getName(), false))
            int nameLength = file.getName().length()
            files.each {
                File logFile ->
                    String datePart
                    try {
                        datePart = logFile.getName().substring(nameLength)
                        Date date = sdf.parse(datePart)
                        if (date.before(cutoffDate)) {
                            logFile.delete()
                        } else if (compress) {
                            zipAndDelete(logFile)
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception pe) {
                        //This isn't a file we should touch (it isn't named correctly)
                    }
            }
        }
        rollOver()
    }

    class StartsWithFileFilter implements FileFilter {
        private String startsWith
        private boolean inclDirs = false

        public StartsWithFileFilter(String startsWith, boolean includeDirectories) {
            super()
            this.startsWith = startsWith.toUpperCase()
            inclDirs = includeDirectories
        }

        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            if (!inclDirs && pathname.isDirectory()) {
                return false
            } else {
                String upperCase = pathname.getName().toUpperCase()
                return upperCase.startsWith(startsWith) && upperCase.length() > startsWith.length()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Compresses the passed file to a .zip file, stores the .zip in the
     * same directory as the passed file, and then deletes the original,
     * leaving only the .zipped archive.
     * @param file
     */
    private void zipAndDelete(File file) throws IOException {
        if (!file.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
            File zipFile = new File(file.getParent(), file.getName() + ".zip")
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile)
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.getName())
            zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry)

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]
            while (true) {
                int bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)
                if (bytesRead == -1) break
                else {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                }
            }
            zos.closeEntry()
            fis.close()
            zos.close()
            file.delete()
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
        long n = System.currentTimeMillis()

        Field field_now = DailyRollingFileAppender.getDeclaredField("now")
        field_now.setAccessible(true)
        Date now = field_now.get(this) as Date

        Field field_rc = DailyRollingFileAppender.getDeclaredField("rc")
        field_rc.setAccessible(true)
        def rc = field_rc.get(this)

        if (n >= nextCheck) {
            now.setTime(n)
            nextCheck = rc.getNextCheckMillis(now)
            try {
                cleanupAndRollOver()
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                LogLog.error("cleanupAndRollover() failed.", ioe)
            }
        }
        super.subAppend(event)
    }
}
```

And to create an appender:

```
appender("ROLLING", CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender) {
    file("$logDirectory/logs/root.log")
    layout(EnhancedPatternLayout) {
        Pattern = "%d %level %thread %mdc %logger - %m%n"
    }
    maxNumberOfDays(30)
    compress(true)
}
```